# IntelliSense: a value of type "PVOID" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "_NtQuerySystemInformation"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, nt

I want know all handles of files that is opened by a determinated process and i have this following code that was found [here](https://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html), but when is passed to VS comes a error saying:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "PVOID" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "_NtQuerySystemInformation"

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(x) ((x) >= 0)
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH 0xc0000004

#define SystemHandleInformation 16
#define ObjectBasicInformation 0
#define ObjectNameInformation 1
#define ObjectTypeInformation 2

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQuerySystemInformation)(
    ULONG SystemInformationClass,
    PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG SystemInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtDuplicateObject)(
    HANDLE SourceProcessHandle,
    HANDLE SourceHandle,
    HANDLE TargetProcessHandle,
    PHANDLE TargetHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    ULONG Attributes,
    ULONG Options
    );
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtQueryObject)(
    HANDLE ObjectHandle,
    ULONG ObjectInformationClass,
    PVOID ObjectInformation,
    ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
{
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG HandleCount;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _POOL_TYPE
{
    NonPagedPool,
    PagedPool,
    NonPagedPoolMustSucceed,
    DontUseThisType,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAligned,
    PagedPoolCacheAligned,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAlignedMustS
} POOL_TYPE, *PPOOL_TYPE;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
{
    UNICODE_STRING Name;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG TotalPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG HighWaterPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG InvalidAttributes;
    GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
    ULONG ValidAccess;
    BOOLEAN SecurityRequired;
    BOOLEAN MaintainHandleCount;
    USHORT MaintainTypeList;
    POOL_TYPE PoolType;
    ULONG PagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG NonPagedPoolUsage;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, *POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;

PVOID GetLibraryProcAddress(PSTR LibraryName, PSTR ProcName)
{
    return GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(LibraryName), ProcName);
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    _NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation = 
        GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    _NtDuplicateObject NtDuplicateObject =
        GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtDuplicateObject");
    _NtQueryObject NtQueryObject =
        GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQueryObject");
    NTSTATUS status;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo;
    ULONG handleInfoSize = 0x10000;
    ULONG pid;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    ULONG i;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: handles [pid]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = _wtoi(argv[1]);

    if (!(processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pid)))
    {
        printf("Could not open PID %d! (Don't try to open a system process.)\n", pid);
        return 1;
    }

    handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)malloc(handleInfoSize);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation won't give us the correct buffer size, 
       so we guess by doubling the buffer size. */
    while ((status = NtQuerySystemInformation(
        SystemHandleInformation,
        handleInfo,
        handleInfoSize,
        NULL
        )) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation stopped giving us STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH. */
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("NtQuerySystemInformation failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];
        HANDLE dupHandle = NULL;
        POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION objectTypeInfo;
        PVOID objectNameInfo;
        UNICODE_STRING objectName;
        ULONG returnLength;

        /* Check if this handle belongs to the PID the user specified. */
        if (handle.ProcessId != pid)
            continue;

        /* Duplicate the handle so we can query it. */
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtDuplicateObject(
            processHandle,
            handle.Handle,
            GetCurrentProcess(),
            &dupHandle,
            0,
            0,
            0
            )))
        {
            printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object type. */
        objectTypeInfo = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectTypeInformation,
            objectTypeInfo,
            0x1000,
            NULL
            )))
        {
            printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object name (unless it has an access of 
           0x0012019f, on which NtQueryObject could hang. */
        if (handle.GrantedAccess == 0x0012019f)
        {
            /* We have the type, so display that. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (did not get name)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
                );
            free(objectTypeInfo);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        objectNameInfo = malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectNameInformation,
            objectNameInfo,
            0x1000,
            &returnLength
            )))
        {
            /* Reallocate the buffer and try again. */
            objectNameInfo = realloc(objectNameInfo, returnLength);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
                dupHandle,
                ObjectNameInformation,
                objectNameInfo,
                returnLength,
                NULL
                )))
            {
                /* We have the type name, so just display that. */
                printf(
                    "[%#x] %.*S: (could not get name)\n",
                    handle.Handle,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
                    );
                free(objectTypeInfo);
                free(objectNameInfo);
                CloseHandle(dupHandle);
                continue;
            }
        }

        /* Cast our buffer into an UNICODE_STRING. */
        objectName = *(PUNICODE_STRING)objectNameInfo;

        /* Print the information! */
        if (objectName.Length)
        {
            /* The object has a name. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: %.*S\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer,
                objectName.Length / 2,
                objectName.Buffer
                );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Print something else. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (unnamed)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
                );
        }

        free(objectTypeInfo);
        free(objectNameInfo);
        CloseHandle(dupHandle);
    }

    free(handleInfo);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

How solve this problem?

Thank in advance.

Comment: IntelliSense errors are fairly meaningless. It uses a different compiler front-end. Post real compiler errors instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast pointer to void to pointer to function. Note that in general case size of pointer to function and size of pointer to data may be not the same.

```
_NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation{};
{
    auto const p_proc{GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation")};
    assert(p_proc); // TODO handle error...
    static_assert(sizeof(_NtQuerySystemInformation) == sizeof(p_proc), "pointer size mismatch");
    memcpy(&NtQuerySystemInformation, &p_proc, sizeof(NtQuerySystemInformation)); // deep copy
}
```

in case of C (because code in your question actually seems to be written in C):

```
_NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation = NULL;

{
    PVOID const p_proc = GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    assert(p_proc); // TODO handle error...
    assert(sizeof(_NtQuerySystemInformation) == sizeof(p_proc));
    memcpy(&NtQuerySystemInformation, &p_proc, sizeof(NtQuerySystemInformation)); // deep copy
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is compile time, not runtime. It would either be true or false, and hence `assert` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ajay Since C does not have `static_assert` using normal `assert` still makes sense.

Comment: For expressing it here, yes. But in actual code, no. I would hand-craft a static assert where `static_assert` isn't available.